# Import multiple csv files to specific sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, csv-import

I have three csv files named CAT.csv, BAT.csv and MAT.csv in a folder located at Z:\Data. I want these csv files to be imported to a workbook named "Daily check" which has individual sheets named CAT, BAT and MAT. I want CAT.csv file to be imported to CAT sheet and BAT.csv file to be imported to BAT sheet and MAT.csv file to be imported to MAT sheet located in workbook "daily check" by using a macro. In addition to it if any of the csv files were not found in a folder, then a message box should appear as "file not found" and should also specify what file was not found, then rest of the code should run and other imports should work. I have a code which works for importing one csv file but not able to modify it to work for all csv files.

```
Sub ImportCSV()
    Const strFileName = "Z:\Data\CAT.csv"
    If Dir$("C:\Users\mbollineni\Desktop\To do\New folder\CAT.csv") = "" Then
   MsgBox "CAT File not found"
  End If
  Dim wbkS As Workbook
  Dim wshS As Worksheet
  Dim wshT As Worksheet
  Set wshT = Worksheets("CAT")
      Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=strFileName)
  Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
  wshS.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")`enter code here`
  wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try repeating the code 3 times and changing the required names like sheet name, address etc ?

Comment: Yes, i did but didnt work. Duplicate string compilation error came up.

Answer (score 2):

Like the below, Copy it one more time for the last file.

```
Sub ImportCSV()

' For CAT File

    strFileName = "Z:\Data\CAT.csv"
    If dir$("C:\Users\mbollineni\Desktop\To do\New folder\CAT.csv") = "" Then
   MsgBox "CAT File not found"
  End If
  Dim wbkS As Workbook
  Dim wshS As Worksheet
  Dim wshT As Worksheet
  Set wshT = Worksheets("CAT")
      Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileName)
  Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
  wshS.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")
  wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False

' For MAT file

    strFileName = "Z:\Data\MAT.csv"
    If dir$("C:\Users\mbollineni\Desktop\To do\New folder\MAT.csv") = "" Then
   MsgBox "MAT File not found"
  End If
  Dim wbkS As Workbook
  Dim wshS As Worksheet
  Dim wshT As Worksheet
  Set wshT = Worksheets("MAT")
      Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileName)
  Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
  wshS.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")
  wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False




End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't work. It says duplicate declaration in current scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `.Copy` but I didn't want to change any logic:

```
Public Enum FileToImport
    [_Start] = 1
        CAT = 1
        BAT = 2
        MAT = 3
    [_End] = 3
End Enum

Function WorksheetToUse(FileNumber As FileToImport) As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    Select Case FileNumber
        Case FileToImport.CAT: wsName = "CAT"
        Case FileToImport.BAT: wsName = "BAT"
        Case FileToImport.MAT: wsName = "MAT"
    End Select
    Set WorksheetToUse = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
End Function

Function FileNameToUse(FileNumber As FileToImport) As String
    Select Case FileNumber
        Case FileToImport.CAT: FileNameToUse = "CAT.csv"
        Case FileToImport.BAT: FileNameToUse = "BAT.csv"
        Case FileToImport.MAT: FileNameToUse = "MAT.csv"
    End Select
End Function

Function FileExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = Dir(strFullPath) <> ""
End Function

Sub ImportCSV()
    Const strDefaultFolder As String = "Z:\Data\"
    Dim wbkS As Workbook
    Dim wshS As Worksheet
    Dim wshT As Worksheet
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim strErr As String
    Dim strFullPath As String

    For lCounter = FileToImport.[_Start] To FileToImport.[_End]
        strFullPath = strDefaultFolder & FileNameToUse(lCounter)
        If FileExists(strFullPath) Then
            Set wshT = WorksheetToUse(lCounter)
            Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(strfullname)
            Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
            wshS.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")
            wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Else
            strErr = strErr & vbNewLine & FileNameToUse(lCounter) & " not found"
        End If
    Next lCounter

    If strErr <> "" Then
        MsgBox Mid(strErr, 3), vbExclamation, "File not found!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure, How to workout with this. I am not familiar with Enum. I do not want to use import option as import of CSV doesn't handle line breaks. Is there any other alternative way please. In addition to it if file was not found a pop up should come saying File not found and Do you want to continue?, if clicked on Yes, it should proceed without that file.